# Visual Studio 2019 typescript: Intellisense reports errors that are not errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Suddently these errors show in the Error list tab:

[image]

But they do not appear in the file itself, everythings works as expected, even F12.

[image]

---

@types/node in `package.json` (also there's vue, vue-property-decorator, etc).

[image]

[image]

Using `TypeScript 2.9`

[image]

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
    "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

those are typescript compilation error.

are you using external tool (like webpack) to compile typescript? if so disable typescript compilation (but keep intellisense) by adding the following to your project's csproj file:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```